# how to form a dictionary by combining two list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

i have the following issue  i have two list need to form a dictionary

```
header=["a","b","c"]
list=[1,2,4,5,7,9,6,5,1,5,8,12]
```

This is how i want the **result** to look like

```
{
  outer1:{
    inner1:{
      "a":1,
      "b":2,
      "c":4,
    },
    inner2:{
      "a":5,
      "b":7,
      "c":9,
    },
    }
  outer2:{
     inner1:{
      "a":6,
      "b":5,
      "c":1,
    },
    inner2:{
      "a":5,
      "b":8,
      "c":12,
    },

  }
}
```

i will appreciate your help incase anything needs clarification kindly comment

below is how i tried to solve the issue

```
dictionary = {"outer" + str(h+1): {"inner" + str(i): {
            header[j]: list[h*len(header)+j] for j in range(len(header))} for i in
            range(3)} for h
            in range(len(list) // len(header))}
```

Comment: Please show case your attempts in solving the problem.

Comment: what is the expected output if the length of the list 15?

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-two-lists-into-a-dictionary/amp/

Comment: @sushanth i have updated my solution kindly review it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution that scales for any number of headers, values and outer dicts.

- `generate_inner_dicts` takes a list of headers and a generator of `values`, consuming (up to) the count of `headers` values from the `values` and zips them up into dicts e.g. `{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 4}` until it's run out of `values`
- `generate_nested_dicts` takes that generator and nests them into the structure required, until it runs out of content in the `inner_dict_generator`.

```
from itertools import count


def generate_inner_dicts(header, values):
    values = iter(values)
    while True:
        inner = dict(zip(header, values))
        if not inner:
            break
        yield inner


def generate_nested_dicts(inner_dict_generator):
    root = {}
    try:
        for outer_count in count(1):
            for inner_count in range(10, 60, 5):
                inner_dict = next(inner_dict_generator)
                outer = root.setdefault(f"outer{outer_count}", {})
                outer[f"inner{inner_count}"] = inner_dict
    except StopIteration:  # Ran out of inner dicts
        pass
    return root


header = [f"f{i}" for i in range(1, 30)]
values = list(range(1, 4061))

nd = generate_nested_dicts(generate_inner_dicts(header, values))

print(nd)
```

Comment: If my scenarion  the header has 29 items, i  mean len(header)=29 and the values has len of 4060 i.e len(values) =4060, how can i modify your answer to suit this case with outer loop to start at 1 to 14 and inner loop to start 10 to 60 (10, 60,5) i mean inner loop to be like inner 10, inner15, inner20, ...., inner55

Comment: `generate_inner_dicts()` will work fine as-is with those specs; `generate_nested_dicts()` needs a change to `inner_count`. I edited my answer to match that.

Comment: worked like charm, thanks

Answer (score 3):

This will create a dictionary as you want it to be:

```
header_raw=["a","b","c"]
li=[1,2,4,5,7,9,6,5,1,5,8,12]

header=header_raw*int(len(li) / len(header_raw))

len_r = len(header_raw)
iterations = int(len(li)/len(header_raw))
ind2_iterations = int(iterations/2)

{f"outer {index}": {f"inner {ind2}": {header[i+index*len_r]:li[i+(((index*2)+ind2)*len_r)] for i in range(len_r)} for ind2 in range(0,ind2_iterations)} for index in range(0,ind2_iterations)}
```

First make both lists the same size.
Then create some helper variables, that help you to iterate through the dict of depth 3.
It would look nicer without **dict comprehention**, but it might help you out.

Comment: i don't think this answer is complete where are u getting the value of **header**  from? do u need to correct something?

Comment: Right, header should be header_raw, it was still in my jupyter session. Thanks for the hint! I updated my solution

Comment: if the header has 29 items, i  mean len(header)=29 and the list has len of 4060 i.e len(li) =4060, how can i modify your answer to suit this case with outer loop to start at 1 to 14 and inner loop to start 10 to 60 (10, 60,5) i mean inner loop to be like inner 10, inner15, inner20, ...., inner55

Answer (score 3):

Here's an [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) based one. You'd only need to parameterise it based on the criteria you're following to structure the output dictionary, that is, the amount of iterations of the outer and inner loops:

```
from itertools import islice, repeat

header=["a","b","c"]
l=iter([1,2,4,5,7,9,6,5,1,5,8,12])

d = {}
for i in range(2):
    d_temp = {}
    for j, head in enumerate(repeat(header,2)):
        d_temp[f'inner{j}'] = dict(zip(head,islice(l,0,3)))
    d[f'outer{i}'] = d_temp
```

---

```
print(d)

{'outer0': {'inner0': {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 4},
            'inner1': {'a': 5, 'b': 7, 'c': 9}},
 'outer1': {'inner0': {'a': 6, 'b': 5, 'c': 1},
            'inner1': {'a': 5, 'b': 8, 'c': 12}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to complete the code if you want to consider more cases, but here is an idea:

```
header=["a","b","c"]
my_list=[1,2,4,5,7,9,6,5,1,5,8,12]

dic = {}

for i in range(int(len(my_list)/6)):
    sublist = my_list[:6]
    my_list = my_list[6:]
    
    d1 = {"a":sublist[0], "b":sublist[1], "c":sublist[2]}
    d2 = {"a":sublist[3], "b":sublist[4], "c":sublist[5]}
    
    dic["outer"+str(i+1)] = {"inner1":d1, "inner2":d2}

print(dic)
```

Comment: This is hardcoding the output structure for this example, and is generally bad practice, since it only works for this example

Comment: My idea was to give an easy example. The code can and should be improved.

Comment: this bad practice what if the header has over 1000 items, that will be very difficult to handle for this example it is fine but work for bigger problems